# Inserting scrollable table and DROPDOWN list in pdf through itextpdf in JAVA

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I used [iTextPdf](http://itextpdf.com/) ver 5.4.2 to insert data into the PDF file. Now I have reached at problem where I need to insert one table in which there's lots of rows and I want to make it fixed height with [scrollable functionality](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html).
And added to the problem is I need to add form fields similar to HTML form fields eg: select,textbox,checkbox etc.(I also used other libraries like [fliyngSaucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) with [html-cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/download.php) to change html directly to pdf but it dosen't render select,input and other kind of statement neither it makes my table scrollable)

Comment: Yes through AcroForm fields I was able to insert Textbox and stuff but scrollable table was not achievable.Also I failed to understand how to make dropdown list.

Comment: The concept of a scrollable table doesn't exist in PDF, so that part of the question doesn't really make sense. Making a drop down list (in PDF lingo known as a *Choice* field) is shown in this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=160

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I tested it and it worked. You made my day. ☺☻♥